# How do I compare dates in C# from User Input?

Tags: c#, date, user-input

This is my code. So what I would like to do is make a game where the user keeps track of the time and guesses what the current time it is. However, I am getting an error that I cannot compare an int to DateTime.

```
   using System;

    namespace DateCheck
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                int dt1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

                if (dt1.Date == dt2.Date)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("yup");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("nope");

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You declare `dt1` as `int` and then expect it to somehow be a `DateTime` four lines later?

Comment: Hi there, could you elaborate? I don't understand. I have kept it as an integer. I want to compare it to the current date?

Comment: why was this upvoted though? Please upvote when the question is of good quality and useful to others as well.

Comment: [Why should I upvote a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question)

Comment: You can't compare an `int` and a `DateTime` because they're conceptually incompatible. An `int` is not a date/time. If you tell someone you have an appointment at 11:00 on 74657, they're going to be confused.  *(An integer in terms of 100-nanosecond increments from a reference point is* almost *a date/time value, but that's also an implementation detail.)*

Comment: Hi, Where can I ask questions about my personal projects?

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly getting the user input as a string but you you need to convert it to a `DateTime` datatype and not to an `Int32` (int).

Try this instead:

`DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Your program might have some other challenges as well, for example:
`DateTime.Now` will return the current time up to a millisecond precision. Your user will most likely not guess it correctly.

Comment: I changed my code with Philip's suggestion. It works well and is by date only. Thank you for all of your help and advice.